# why sizeof(13.33) is 8 bytes?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

When I give `sizeof(a)`, where `a=13.33`, a float variable, the size is 4 bytes.
But if i give `sizeof(13.33)` directly, the size is 8 bytes.

I do not understand what is happening. Can someone help?

Comment: Dude, stop adding and removing the `math` tag to bump this question to the top.

Comment: try 13.ff instead and also refer this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor

Comment: [Why floating point value such as 3.14 are considered as double by default in MSVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4353780/995714)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Those are the rules of the language.

13.33 is a numeric literal. It is treated as a double because it is a double. If you want 13.33 to be treated as a float literal, then you state 13.33f.

13.33 is a double literal. If sizeof(float) == 4, sizeof(13.33f) == 4 should also hold because 13.33f is a float literal.

Answer (score 19):

The literal 13.33 is treated as a double precision floating point value, 8 bytes wide.

Comment: To explicitly mark a number literal as a single precision float, try `13.33f`. `sizeof(13.33f)` returns the expected 4.

Answer (score 13):

The 13.33 literal is being treated as 'double', not 'float'.

Try 13.33f instead.

Answer (score 9):

The type and size of your variable are fine. **It's just that the compiler has some default types for literals, those constant values hard-coded in your program**.

If you request `sizeof(1)`, you'll get `sizeof(int)`. If you request `sizeof(2.5)`, you'll get `sizeof(double)`. Those would clearly fit into a char and a float respectively, but the compiler has default types for your literals and will treat them as such until assignment.

You can override this default behaviour, though. For example:

```
2.5 // as you didn't specify anything, the compiler will take it for a double.
2.5f // ah ha! you're specifying this literal to be float
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

Because `13.33` is a `double`, which gets truncated to a `float` if you assign it. And a `double` is 8bytes. To create a real float, use `13.33f` (note the `f`).