# float data type(5.0) being assigned 8 bytes rather that 4 using sizeof operator in C

Tags: c, sizeof

Why does `sizeof(5.0)` return 8 as its output rather than 4 as my machine allocates 4 bytes for a `float` data type?
Does it by default consider `5.0` as a `double` (memory allocated = 8 bytes), if yes then why is it so?

Comment: [why sizeof(13.33) is 8 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5537276/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all floating point literals default to `double`. If you want it to be a `float` then use the `f` suffix as in `5.0f`.

Read e.g. [this floating point constant (literal) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

N1570 (latest C11 draft), **§6.4.4.2 p4**:

> An unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`. If suffixed by the letter `f` or `F`, it has
>   type `float`. If suffixed by the letter `l` or `L`, it has type `long double`.

---

As for your "*why*" question, in practice, `float` is rarely useful due to its very limited precision, so this default "makes sense". Don't bother using `float` at all if you don't have strong reasons (like e.g. very limited memory constraints). If you *really* need a `float` constant, write `5.0f`.

Comment: It is interesting to note that while we consider `float` to be of limited precision, there are several machine learning applications for which `float` is also too large (and takes up too much space in case of huge matrices) and hence they are looking at half-precision.