# Function overloading in C++. Does not work with float, works with double

Tags: c++, overloading

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int square(int x);
float square(float x);

int main() {
    cout<<square(3);
    cout<<square(3.14);

    return 0;
}

int square(int x) {
    cout<<"\nINT version called\n";
    return x*x;
}

float square(float x) {
    cout<<"\nFLOAT version called\n";
    return x*x;
}
```

I have tried to replace the float version of a function with double one, and it starts to work then. What is the problem here? Cannot 3.14 be considered as float?

> error: call of overloaded 'square(double)' is ambiguous
>   note: candidates are:
>   note: int square(int)
>   note: float square(float)

Comment: Convert to `(float)` or use `f` in your literal (`3.14f`) if you want to. I'd recommend using `double` though as it has more precision and it is the default floating point as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353780/why-floating-point-value-such-as-3-14-are-considered-as-double-by-default-in-msv).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Floating-point literals in C++ are of type `double`. Conversions from `double` to `int` and `float` do not have an ordering defined, so your call is ambiguous.

If you want to call the `float` function, call it with a `float` literal:

```
cout<<square(3.14f);
//note the f here^
```

Answer (score 0):

3.14 is taken as a double by the compiler . It does not find a function with double argument and is confused if it should convert the double to int or float .Therefore either try below code or use double in function declaration.

```
 cout<<square(3.14f);
```