# double or float

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use double or float ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074474/should-i-use-double-or-float)

When would I rather use double and when should I use float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about precision.

If you need to store very precise numbers then use a double.

If you need to store less precise numbers and are worried about the size of memory you're using then use a float.

Answer (score 2):

The only time you need to use `float` is when you are storing large arrays of numbers. There is generally little difference in speed between the two and natively most things are `double` anyway.

Comment: The speed difference is extremely dependent on the HW you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Use `double` when you require the range it supports. Refer to [Range of floating-point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Range_of_floating-point_numbers). You should also typically use the native type, so if you're doing graphics or GPU programming, probably better stick to floats.

But whatever you do, please, do not use either to represent currency or money.

Comment: @lital: Because it cannot represent most decimal fractions. Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ to understand why and what that means.

Comment: Unless your currency has coins (and prices) for base-2 fractions. :)

Comment: even then it isn't necessarily appropriate you may need to track cents at the same time as tracking trillions of dollars