# The output of the program is always '0'?

Tags: c++, loops, casting

I want to find the sum up to the 'n'th term for the following series:

(1/2)+((1*3)/(2*4))+((1*3*5)/(2*4*6))....

So, I wrote the following program in c++ :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int p=1, k=1, n=0;
float h=0;
cout<<"Enter the term: ";
cin>>n;
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
    {
        p*=((2*j)-1);
        k*=(2*j);
    }
    h+=(p/k);
    p=1;
    k=1;

}
cout<<"The sum is : "<<h;
return 0;
getch();

}
```

However, the output of the program always gives me '0'. I can't figure out the problem with the program.

N.B. I'm new to programming.

Comment: The expression `p/k` with `int p` and `int k` looks like a bad idea in the context of what you're hoping to achieve, since it gives an integer result (for example, `1/2 == 0`). You might want to use `float` or `double` instead...

Comment: try `(float)p / k` instead of `p/k`

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single-step through the code, *watching* values of variables.  Often, debugging is faster than creating a correct post to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to inspect your code or debug your code for you.

Comment: Just change `h+=(p/k)` to `h+=((p*1.0)/k)` so that p/k will be converted to floating point value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you haven't declared `p` and `k` as `float` or `double`or explicitly cast them as such before the calculation and assignment to `h`.

What's happening is for every iteration of the loop `p < k` (by nature of the problem) since `p` and `k` are both declared as `int`, `p / k = 0`. So you're just summing 0 for every iteration.

Either declare `p` and `k` as `float` or `double` or do this:

```
h += ((float) p) / ((float) k)
```

Also, for this specific problem I assume you're looking for precision, so be wary and look into that as well [Should I use double or float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074474/should-i-use-double-or-float)

Answer (score 0):

implicit conversion and type casting are a trap where all newbies fall.
in the instruction:

```
h += p/k;
```

the compiler performs an integer division first, then a promotion of the result to floating point type.
and since:

```
p < k ; for all i,j < n
```

then:

```
res = (p / k) < 1 => truncates to 0;  // by integer division
```

thus:

```
sum(1->n) of p/k = sum (1->n) 0 = 0;
```

finally:

```
h = conversion to float of (0) = 0.0f;
```

that's why you have the result of 0.0f at the end.

the solution:

1- first of all you need to use the natural type for floating point of c++ which is "double" (under the hood c++ promotes float to double, so use it directly).

2- declare all your variable as double, except the number of terms n:

3- the number of terms is never negative, you need to express that in your code by declaring it as an unsigned int.

4- if you do step 3, make sure to catch overflow errors, that is if the user enters a negative number your risk to have a very big number in "n", expel : n =-1 converts to 0xffffffff positive number.

5- engineer your code sometimes is better.

6- include only the headers that you need, and avoid a importing any namespace in your global namespace.

here is how i think you should write your program.

```
#include <iostream>

double sum_serie(unsigned int n)
{
    double prod = 1.0, sum = 0.0;
    for (double c=1; c<=n ; c++)
    {
         prod *= ( ( 2*c ) - 1 ) / ( 2*c ); // remark the parenthesis
         sum += prod;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int n = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    std::cout << " enter the number of terms n: ";
    std::cin  >> temp;
    if (temp > 0) 
        n = temp; // this is how you catch overflow
    else
    {
        std::cout << " n < 0, no result calculated " << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << " the result is sum = " << sum_serie(n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know that the question was about the implicit conversion and casting in C++, but even the way of writing a code can show you what bugs you have in it, so try to learn a proper way of expressing your ideas into code, debugging comes natural afterward.

Good Luck